# perform mathematical operations on a number without changing the attached text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula that can multiply or divide all the numbers in a string without changing the text attached to the numbers.

I need the numbers in the next column to automatically change according to the given mathematical operation, but the text from the original line must remain unchanged.

I've tried using a combination of REGEXMATCH and REGEXEXTRACT and by doing this I just get the result of multiplying/dividing all the numbers in the string (no text whatsoever).

I also had no success using REGEXREPLACE. I'm not even sure we can actually use it in this case, and maybe I need a different formula instead. Maybe you first need to extract the numbers, multiply them and use something like TEXTJOIN or CONCATENATE to put them together in a string with the values already changed, and is this even possible in this specific example? It's totally fine to perform the operation in several steps if needed (for example, adding SPLIT function or something like that), but the format of the raw data we need to enter and recalculate, unfortunately, cannot be modified.

A sample table for better visualisation can be seen below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

| Raw data | Operation | Desired outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25STR/40DEX/70FRES | *0.25 | 6.25STR/10DEX/17.5FRES |
| 80VIT/30INT/50CRES | *0.75 | 60STR/22.5INT/37.5CRES |
| 60VIT/20STR/45LRES | *1.25 | 75VIT/25STR/56.25LRES |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(index(bycol(split(A2:A,"/"),lambda(z,ifna(ifs(left(B2:B,1)="*",regexextract(z,"\d+")*mid(B2:B,2,99),left(B2:B,1)="/",round(regexextract(z,"\d+")/mid(B2:B,2,99),2))&regexextract(z,"\d+(.*)"))))),lambda(y,if(y="",,join("/",y))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! 

I have one more question. I should have mentioned this in the original post, so I already accepted the suggested solution, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do the operation in just one cell (without the B column in this case)?

[like in this picture](https://i.imgur.com/XL9lTnt.png)

Comment: Within your case scenario how are we goin' to supply these Column B values to the formula for calculation part?

Comment: The idea is that the calculations should work with any values that could be set directly in the formula. But just to check if it works, we can use the values ​​from the original post: B2 = A2 * 0.25, B3 = A3 * 0.75, etc.

Comment: well if we are hardcoding the values direct into the formula; you may try this for row 2 in the sample data `=join("/",bycol(split(A2,"/"),lambda(z,regexextract(z,"\d+")*0.25&regexextract(z,"\d+(.*)"))))`

Comment: I'm very sorry for another question, but is there also a way to modify the formula so that the result of the multiplication, if necessary, is rounded by a given parameter, for example, to the nearest 10 via MROUND or a similar function? I've tried to do it myself, but it seems like I couldn't find the correct order and get the following error: "Function MROUND parameter 1 expects number values. But 'x' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number" or some errors related to the LAMBDA function itself.

Comment: this: `=join("/",bycol(split(A2,"/"),lambda(z,mround(regexextract(z,"\d+")*0.25,10)&regexextract(z,"\d+(.*)"))))`